# Good 960.gs plugins for Firefox?

Tags: html, css, 960.gs

I am using 960.gs for designing website layouts. I could not able to find a good 960.gs Firefox plugin. What are the good 960.gs Firefox plugins available?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you want but if you are aiming to have the 960 grid show on the browser you can install pixel perfect for firebug. You can change the opacity of the image of the grid. You can also use this: http://peol.github.com/960gridder/